# How to easily switch between Windows 7 and OS X in Boot Camp

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp

I am currently running bootcamp on SnowLeopard OS X with Windows 7.

At present, when I want to switch to Windows 7 from SnowLeopard I have to restart and hold down the option key, only then am I given the options of OS I have installed and can then select Windows 7.

However, I am aware that it can be set up, so that when the laptop is booted up it shows the options of the different OS's without having to hold down the option key.

How would I make it the same as described above?, so that every time I start my laptop up the OS options appear automatically without the need for myself/the user to hold down the option button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/).  I used it back when I had my Macbook Pro triple-booting OS X, Windows XP, and Ubuntu Linux, and it worked very well.  Installation instructions, along with the rest of the documentation, are also available on the site I posted (unfortunately I can't post another link because I just created my account here...).

**EDIT**

Installation Instructions [here](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s1_install.html)
Complete Documentation [here](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/)

Comment: rEFIt is incredible!  Use it!

Comment: so this would allow me upon start up to see all my OS options without having to press a certain key etc?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it does.

Comment: brilliant. best answer tick for you my friend

Answer (score 0):

Bootpicker, from Apple, will handle triple-boot as well. It is an OS X application that runs at login / logout from OS X and allows selection of OS's.

It's designed for educational computer lab managers who want to limit options to what they've decided to offer, while preventing startup from whatever external systems might be present via external hard drive that students might bring in. http://www.apple.com/education/resources/bootpicker/ has more about this. Nothing against rEFIt either, so it depends on your local security needs.